# Calculate P(X > 85) in normal distribution

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We're currently handling normal distribution in class but I'm missing the clue I guess.

We get an assignment like: 
*Calculate the follwing chances: P(X > 85)*

This was my solution:
[image: Solution]

It's given that µ = 70, and G = 10 (standard deviation). We also know that Z must be 1.5 than, because 85 is 1.5 times the standard deviation away from µ.

Than I use the formula: z = (x - µ) / G; do some algebra on it until I get the result x = 85.

However, now I just calculated X, that was not the assignment...
What step am I missing to calculate the **probability** that X > 85?

Comment: Use the statistical tables to find $P(Z>1.5)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X\sim N(70,100)=N(\mu,G^2)$, then $Z= \frac{X-70}{10}\sim N(0,1)$ and thus
\begin{align}
P(X>85)=P\Big(\frac{X-70}{10}>\frac{85-70}{10}\Big)=P(Z>1.5)
\end{align}
The complementary event of $\lbrace Z>1.5\rbrace$ is $\lbrace Z\leq 1.5\rbrace$ and thus
\begin{align}
P(Z>1.5)=1-P(Z\leq 1.5)
\end{align}
Now look into a statistical table! The Keyword is $N(0,1)$-distribution.